# Printing values from a defaultdict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing some code that looks like this:

```
def check_states(inventory):
    inventory_list = defaultdict(list)
    for i in inventory:
        inventory_list[i['store_site']].append(i)
```

This will give me a defaultdict with a key of the `store_site` and a list of all the inventory there, which is information that has data in it in a further dictionary like received date, transferred date, serial number, state, etc.  So it is a dictionary that maps to  multiple values inside of it. So what we have is **dictionary of a list of dictionaries.** I want to print some, but not all of those values. So to the end of the function above I add:

```
for store in inventory_list:
    print(store['serial_id'])
```

and I get

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers.
```

I also have tried using `items()`:

```
for store in inventory_list.items():
    print(store['serial_id'])
```

and I get

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str.
```

Can anyone help show me my error? I looked for similar questions, but most of the dictionary questions are about printing a 1:1 value, not a 1:many value.

```
{'store5278': [{'abstract_state': 'GONE',
'aud_last_updated_time': '2017-03-29T08:03:20Z',
'bin_id': 9178,
'disposed_at': '2017-03-29T08:03:20Z',
'entity_type': 'parts',
'external_serial_id': '',
'id': 8336471,
'is_fake_serial_id': False,
'is_model_active': True,
'is_part_active': True,
'is_vending_bin': False,
'joint_asset_id': '_part_8336471',
'last_updated_time': '2017-03-29T08:03:20Z',
'model': 'Z-CAT6-16M-OR-UTP-AA-L-BBB',
'model_apn': 'OrangePatch16M',
'model_description': 'CAT6 Copper Patch Cord 16m PVC ORANGE ',
'model_id': 7285,
'model_mpn': '',
'po_number': '312949',
'received_at': '2017-03-23T14:38:25Z',
'room': 'PARTS',
'serial_id': '002042869',
'state': 'CONSUMED',
'state_id': '10',
'store': 'store5278',
'tracking_id': '7097553',
'transferred_at': '2017-03-29T08:03:20Z',
'type_id': 27,
'type_name': 'Cable',
'unit_cost': 0.0,
'vendor': 'Excel',
'vendor_id': 135}]}
```

Comment: Can you provide a **[mcve]**? For example, some specific input which we can run to verify your example?

Comment: have you read through the documentation on `defaultdict`s? If the value in the `defaultdict` is another data structure, just iterate through that using the appropriate functions for that data structure.

Comment: Read the documentation about `dict`s. You are not using them correctly. It is very well documented online.

Comment: What's `site` in the last snippet?

Comment: I *think* all you need is `for store in inventory_list.values(): print(store['serial_id'])`, but it's not exactly clear what your desired output is.

Comment: The format is a dictionary of a list of dictionaries. I'm having trouble drilling down to the lower values.  I've added an sample of what the data might look like normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first bit of code

```
for store in inventory_list:
    print(store['serial_id'])
```

is throwing an error because `for k in dictionary` iterates through the keys of a dictionary, setting each key as `k`. When you try to access `store[x]`, you're telling python to access the character in position `x` of string `store`. However, you have used a string (`serial_id`), so python is telling you that it expects an integer.

The second snippet

```
for store in inventory_list.items():
    print(store['serial_id'])
```

makes the same error, but `store` in this case is a tuple of `(key, value)`. The more common way to use this syntax is to access both keys and values, as follows:

```
inventory_list = {
    'store a': { 'apples': 10, 'bananas': 5, 'cows': 2 },
    'store b': { 'apples': 5, 'bananas': 10 } }

for store, stuff in inventory_list.items():
    print( store )
    print( stuff )
```

returns

```
store a
{'apples': 10, 'bananas': 5, 'cows': 2}
store b
{'apples': 5, 'bananas': 10}
```

If you want to iterate through the data within each of the nested dictionaries, do so as if you were accessing a top-level item, i.e.

```
# using the same inventory list as before
for k,v in inventory_list.items():
    print("Inventory for store " + k)
    # v is a reference to a dictionary, so iterate through that
    for item, qtt in v.items():
        print("Item: " + item + "; quantity: " + str(qtt))
```

Output:

```
Inventory for store store a
Item: apples; quantity: 10
Item: bananas; quantity: 5
Item: cows; quantity: 2
Inventory for store store b
Item: apples; quantity: 5
Item: bananas; quantity: 10
```

If you want to access data in the nested dictionary directly, you can do so using by key:

```
for k,v in inventory_list.items():
    print(k + " has " + str(v['apples']) + ' apples in stock')
```

Output:

```
store a has 10 apples in stock
store b has 5 apples in stock
```

If you have a list of dictionaries, you can iterate through it using `for x in list`, where each `x` will be dictionary:

```
inventory_list = [
     { 'apples': 10, 'bananas': 5, 'cows': 2 },
     { 'apples': 5, 'bananas': 10 }]

for store in inventory_list:
    print( store )
```

Output:

```
{'apples': 10, 'bananas': 5, 'cows': 2}
{'apples': 5, 'bananas': 10}
```

or access a value directly:

```
for store in inventory_list:
    print( store['apples'] )
```

Output:

```
10
5
```

Put all this together to access data within a dictionary of lists of dictionaries:

```
dd = { 'store a': [ { 'apples': 10, 'bananas': 5, 'cows': 2 }, { 'apples': 20, 'bananas': 15, 'cows': 25 } ],
      'store b': [{ 'apples': 5, 'bananas': 10 }, {'apples': 2, 'bananas': 30, 'cows': 0}] }

for k,v in dd.items():
    print(k)
    for list_item in v: # v is the list, list_item is each dictionary
        print('apples: ' + str(list_item['apples']))
```

Output:

```
store a
apples: 10
apples: 20
store b
apples: 5
apples: 2
```

If in doubt, I highly recommend adding `print` statements to your code to work out what each variable looks like (is it a string? a tuple? a dictionary? etc.). It will help you immensely with understanding and debugging your code.

All of this information can be gleaned from [reading the python documentation on dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) and [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range).

Comment: Thanks for the details response. I've updated my original question. My issue is that it is a dictionary of a list of dictionaries. I'm having trouble getting to the values inside the last dictionary structure.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was my hang up, I had to iterate down further into the list. I didn't realize you could iterate over the values given by items(). Rate up, and thank you for the multiple responses.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems is not quite understanding the nature of the data being iterated over in your `for` loops. And perhaps not understanding what inside the `inventory` parameter.

```
for store in inventory_list:
    ...
```

`inventory_list` is a `dict`. When iterating over a `dict` as shown above one gets  a sequence of all the `keys` in the dict. In your dict those keys are "apparently" `strings`. I say that by reverse engineering the error you're showing:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers.
```

That's the error one gets when running:

```
stored = "some_name"
store['serial_id']
```

So... first issue for you is to understand the data in `inventory` sequence. The elements apparently have a 'store_site', but that value there is a string, not some higher level data structure.

In your second example:

```
for store in inventory_list.items():
   ...
```

The items() method on a `dict` generates a sequence of key/value tuples. It does not generate a sequence of keys (what I think you equate to "stores"). And that explains why `store['serial_id']` fails as it does.

Comment: I've updated my original post with more information, but inventory_list is actually a dictionary of a list of dictionaries.  If it was a dictionary of a list, I could print the values in the list using .items(), I've done that before.  I don't know how to get down further into this type of data structure